# video upload on laravel returns null

Tags: php, laravel

So im trying to upload a video on my app that i created with laravel, now when i try to upload a picture its working fine, but when i try to upload a video it only returns 'null' i have tried changing the upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
memory_limit = 32M

to a higher number like 200M but still i get null, I tried to look for an answer in the internet but there are plenty of people who has the same problem as i do. this is what i have in my controller and in my view

```
{{Form::open(array('url' => 'Newpost', 'files' => 'true', 'method' => 'post'))}}

            {{Form::label('title', '*Title')}}
            {{Form::text('title', null,array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => 'Title...',),
            ['data-ng-model' => 'title'] 
            )}}<br>

            {{Form::label('content', '*Content')}}
            {{Form::textarea('content',null ,array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => 'Write here...'

            ))}}

            <br>
            {{Form::file('image',array(
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
            ))}}<p class="p">You are only allowed to submit one file photo*</p><br>

            {{Form::file('vid',array(
            'class' => 'btn btn-info'
            ))}}<br>

            {{Form::submit('Publish', array(
            'class' => 'btn btn-default'
            ))}}

        {{Form::close()}}
```

Controller

```
$input = Input::all();
        dd($input);
```

I also tried

```
Input::file('vid');
```

but still it returns error.

Comment: Try using native `_FILES` array. see if it works?

Comment: Make sure your html `<form>`contains `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute

Comment: What HTTP server are you using Apache, nginx? You may have a size limit from the server, not necessarily from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put on your post schemma this:

> $table->string('vid')->nullable();